# Is there a way to assign random.choice results from a txt doc to another txt doc?

Tags: python

I am trying to assign the results of

```
x = 1
while (x < 11):
    names =(random.choice(list(open('AllTickers.txt'))))
    with open("NewStockList.txt", "w") as output:
        for line in names:
            output.write(str(names))
            output.write('\n')
            x = x + 1
```

to a new text doc.

When it ran, it just posted the same string 5 times.

Comment: `output.write(str(names))` should be `output.write(str(line))`. Please also fix the formatting as there's probably another issue that I can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a lot of code to refactor, first of all you need to declare how strings are separated. Get the variable from 'AllTickers.txt' out of loop for performance reasons and read it either with `open` or `pathlib.Path`.

If words or whatever you are checking is separated by linebreaks you can do `.splitlines` to the resulted text otherwise you might need to use `split` declaring the separator.

This will return you a list which can be randomly choose with `random.choice`.
Something like:

```py
import pathlib


tickers = pathlib.Path('AllTickers.txt').read_text()
tickers = tickers.splitlines()  # or `.split`

while a < b:  # Your loop
    ticker = random.choice(tickers)
    # Now do whatever you need with that variable
```

Comment: Ok i didn't format the question properly. the text file has all the lines separated, I just need the program to pick 10 random lines and put it into the newstocklist.txt.
any help here?

Answer (score 0):

What is the need for using both `random.choice` and a `for` loop.
because these two returns only a one item in each loop.

If you need get a random item from the `AllStickers.txt` and save it to `NewStocklist.txt`, then you need read every line in the Allsticker.txt and take a random item from the list and save it to newstocklist.txt.
Also you need to open newstockelist.txt from append mode, not in write mode. Otherwise, in your while loop the previously saved items will be overwritten in each turn.

```
import random 

names = list(open("AllStickers.txt", "r").readlines())

x = 0
while x < 11:
   with open("new.txt", "a") as  output: 
       line = random.choice (names) 
       output.write(str(line)) 
       x = x+1 
       continue
```

If you need to take items from `AllSticker.txt` and write them into the `NewStockList.txt`, then use a for loop and read every line in AllStickers.txt .

```
names = list(open("AllStickers.txt", "r").readlines())

x = 0
while x < 11:
    with open("NewStockList.txt", "a") as output:
        for line in names:
            output.write(str(line)) 
            x = x+1 
            continue
```

Comment: THANK YOU. its nice to finally find an answer to a question you have been trying to find the answer to for 5 hours